# Oracle Sql case statement with Multiple values in then

Tags: sql, oracle

I Want to write oracle sql cases with multiple conditions with multiple output values.

For instance,

```
SELECT A,B,
  Case
  When A In(default, non default, Deliquent)  Then ('dl_vint','lw_vint','hg_vint')
from Application
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

SQL queries support `case` **expressions**.  An expression returns a single value.  I assume that you want something like this:

```
select A, B,
       (case when A = 'default' then 'dl_vint'
             when A = 'non default' then 'lw_vint'
             when A = 'Deliquent' then 'hg_vint'
        end)
from Application
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
SELECT  
  A, B, 
  case A 
    when 'default' THEN 'dl_vint'
    when 'non default' then 'lw_vint'
    when 'Deliquent' then 'hg_vint'
  end
from Application
```